# Convert list to 3D Array in C#

Tags: c#, list, multidimensional-array

does anyone know how to convert a List to a 3D Array?. My input list will actually always be a "flattened" verison of a 3D Array, so I will always know the arrays dimensions. Any clues would be great

```
        T[,] output = new T[height, width];
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                output[i, j] = input[i * width + j];
            }
        }
```

This is to convert a List/Array to a 2D Array, but I dont seem to wrap my head around to convert to a 3D Array

Comment: Well it depends how it was flattened in the first place.

Comment: @Guy A Java question?

Comment: Just use three for loops and calculate the index into the list for each array element. Try it for two dimensions and you will see how.

Comment: I suppose It was just converted in to a List by mantianing the same sequence of elements

Comment: "I suppose" isn't any use to us, how can we possibly answer!

Comment: `T[,] output = new T[height, width];
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                {
                    output[i, j] = input[i * width + j];
                }
            }`

Answer (score 2):

You will need to know each dimension of the three of the 3D array. Lets say they are `d1`, `d2`, and `d3`, then you can use this code to get the array you want, assuming an `int` array:

```cs
int i, j, k, p;
int[,,] Arr = new int[d1, d2, d3];
p = 0;
for (i = 0; i < d1; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < d2; j++)
        for (k = 0; k < d3; k++)
            a[i, j, k] = lst[p++];
```

If you want a solution similar to you example you can try this:

```cs
int i, j, k;
int[,,] Arr = new int[d1, d2, d3];
for (i = 0; i < d1; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < d2; j++)
        for (k = 0; k < d3; k++)
            a[i, j, k] = lst[i * d2 * d3 + j * d3 + k];
```

Comment: @Nicholas Rawitscher I added another answer based on your example.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            a[i, j ,k] = x;
```

Comment: You really should include some commentary about your code. Why is this the right code?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to know which order the items were stored in when going from an array to a list, and from that you can see how to calculate the index into the list:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // N.B. You will have to pick which order the dimensions go in.
            var ni = 4;
            var nj = 3;
            var nk = 2;

            // Make a list that could be interpreted as a 3-d array:
            var x = new List<string>();
            for (int k = 0; k < nk; k++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < nj; j++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ni; i++)
                    {
                        x.Add($"{k}-{j}-{i}");
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", x));

            // Copy the content of the list to a 3-d array:
            string[,,] array1 = new string[nk, nj, ni];

            for (int k = 0; k < nk; k++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < nj; j++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ni; i++)
                    {
                        var idx = i + j * (nj + 1) + k * (nk + 1) * (nj + 1);
                        array1[k, j, i] = x[idx];
                        Console.Write(array1[k, j, i] + ", ");
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs, for confirmation,

> 0-0-0, 0-0-1, 0-0-2, 0-0-3, 0-1-0, 0-1-1, 0-1-2, 0-1-3, 0-2-0, 0-2-1, 0-2-2, 0-2-3, 1-0-0, 1-0-1, 1-0-2, 1-0-3, 1-1-0, 1-1-1, 1-1-2, 1-1-3, 1-2-0, 1-2-1, 1-2-2, 1-2-3
>   0-0-0, 0-0-1, 0-0-2, 0-0-3, 0-1-0, 0-1-1, 0-1-2, 0-1-3, 0-2-0, 0-2-1, 0-2-2, 0-2-3, 1-0-0, 1-0-1, 1-0-2, 1-0-3, 1-1-0, 1-1-1, 1-1-2, 1-1-3, 1-2-0, 1-2-1, 1-2-2, 1-2-3,